# How to take form string value from CharField and convert into object instance in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I keep running into this error:

Cannot assign "u'Foo Group'": "Team.membership_group" must be a "Group" instance.

In my Django application, I give the user an option to create a Team. The team has a memebership_group ForeignKey attribute which maps to 'Group' (django.contrib.auth.models.Group). In the form, I've changed the widget to be a CharField so that if a group that the user types isn't actually a group, my code *should* create it. Here is my form:

```
class TeamForm(ModelForm):
   """Form to create and modify systems"""

    membership_group = CharField()

    manager = ModelChoiceField(queryset=Manager.objects.all(), required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = ['name', 'manager', 'membership_group']
```

In my views (or possibly I need to write the code elsewhere?), I want to take the string value and run a get_or_create to either return the existing group or create a new one. Here is the code in my views that isn't working:

```
class TeamCreateView(AutoEventLogMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    """View to create Teams"""

    form_class = TeamForm
    model = Team
    permission_required = 'teams.add_team'
    success_message = "Team '%(name)s' created successfully."
    template_name = 'teams/team_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):

        team_created = super(TeamCreateView, self).form_valid(form)

        team = self.object

        group_name = form.instance.membership_group

        group_name.encode('utf-8')

        membership_group = Group.objects.get_or_create(name=group_name)[0]

        team.membership_group = membership_group

        team.save()

        return team_created
```

What am I doing wrong? What code do I need to add (and where) to be able to serialize/deserialize the membership group value from string to group and vice versa

Comment: `team.membership_group` is a `CharField()` in your model. So either assign a string to it like `team.membership_group =group_name`, or make it a [`ForeignKey` field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey).

Comment: team.membership_group is a ForeignKey(Group) in my model.

Comment: Sorry, I read it too fast. What's the relation between `Team` and `AccountableTeam` in your code?

Comment: they are the same, sorry I'll fix that in my question

Comment: That makes sense, the class `TeamForm` is trying to assign the value of its `membership_group`, which is a string, to the field with identical name in `Team`. `form_valid` isn't the correct place to put your type-casting code.

Comment: Probably why I'm running into errors. Where **do** I put my type-casting code?

Comment: I guess that defining `CharField()` in `TeamForm` with another name should solve the error. There is no reason to bind the `CharField` in the form to the `ForreignKey` field in the model, if you plan to do it explicitly.

Comment: I don't think you are understanding the question because that's not what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to take that value that I get from the CharField and get_or_create an instance of the Group object when I create a new team. The problem is that when I try to create a new team, it tries assigning that string value to the ForeignKey. I want to take that string value, get or create a group object, then assign it to the ForeignKey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in anyway it is not a good idea to do type translation in `form_valid`. If you use django1.9, then consider to create a customized [FormField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/validation/#form-field-default-cleaning):

```
from django import forms

class MyGroupField(forms.Field):
    def to_python(self, group_name):
        return Group.objects.get_or_create(name=group_name)[0]

class TeamForm(ModelForm):
    membership_group = MyGroupField()
```